# ActiveMQ - create embedded broker listening on SSL (TLS) transport error

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I would like to create an embedded ActiveMQ broker that listens on SSL protocol using client authentication mechanism (TLS).

Here's my code that expects to do so :

```
//loading keystore from file    
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

File ksfile = new File("/home/me/client1.pkcs12");
FileInputStream ksfis = new FileInputStream(ksfile);

keystore.load(ksfis, "password".toCharArray());

//loading truststore from file
KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
truststore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/me/client1.truststore")), "password"
                .toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
        .getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(truststore);

//broker definition
String cfURI = "ssl://localhost:2032";
BrokerService brokerService = new BrokerService();
brokerService.addConnector(cfURI);

//configure ssl context for the broker
SslContext sslContext = new SslContext(kmf.getKeyManagers(),tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

//need client authentication
sslContext.getSSLContext().getDefaultSSLParameters().setNeedClientAuth(true);
sslContext.getSSLContext().getDefaultSSLParameters().setWantClientAuth(true);

brokerService.setSslContext(sslContext);
brokerService.start();
```

When i execute the previous code in a main program, i get the following error :

```
GRAVE: Could not accept connection : javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
```

Any suggestions are wellcome !

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Has your client set the certificate from the broker in its truststore? I'm afraid thats the problem you are running into.

Other than that, it would probably help if you paste the client code as well

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by using ActiveMQConnectionFactory instead of ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory when connecting from the client